# FFMPEG decrypt DFM Show "buffer overflow detected" Error

Tags: ffmpeg

[image]

I have the drm key ,but use `ffmpeg` show buffer overflow detected error
mpd link is the live

ffmpeg -cenc_decryption_key key  -i "mpd link" -c copy test.mp4

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023614476a80] Failed to seek for
> auxiliary info, will only parse senc atoms for encryption info
> *** buffer overflow detected ***:  terminated

Comment: Please make the effort to type in the error, it is only one line.  With the image, one has to expand it to read it.

Comment: "Failed to seek for auxilliary info, will only parse senc atoms for encryption info". Have you googled that error?